Rouché's theorem; $z^n(z−2)=1$

Statement: $p(z)=z^n(z−2)-1$ has $n$ zeroes on $D(0,1)$

Considering $f(z)=z^{n+1}-1$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ such that $z^{n+1}\neq-1$ for $z \in \overline{D(1,\epsilon)}$ ;
$$|z^{n+1}-1|<|2z^n|; |z-1|=\epsilon$$
And by Rouché's theorem, $2z^n$ and $p(z)$ should have the same number of zeroes on $D(1,\epsilon)$ but  $2z^n$ has no zeroes on $D(1,\epsilon)$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon$; how could this be helpful?
My doubt arrived from this post: Research the roots of complex equation $x^n(x-2) = 1$

The linked post mentions having zeros in the disc $|z| = 1+\epsilon$, which is $z \in D(0,1+\epsilon)$, not $D(1,\epsilon)$
